# How to specify a log file for testdisk 7.0?

Tags: 14.10, testdisk

According to `testdisk_static --help` options seem to be specified by prepending `/` to a positional argument (I don't believe it, but that's the only way I understand the help); it says

```
Usage: testdisk [/log] [/debug] [file.dd|file.e01|device]
```

I'm using the `testdisk_static` binary which gave me the help message. I tried `sudo testdisk_static //path/to/file.log` and `sudo testdisk_static /path/to/file` which gives me `Unable to open file or device /path/to/file.log: Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

`testdisk_static /version` correctly prints the version and invoking with a file argument only works as well, e.g. `sudo testdisk_static /dev/sdxY`.

I'm using 7.0 on Ubuntu 14.10 amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manpage of testdisk:

```
 /log   create a testdisk.log file
```

I'd say that if you specify `/log`, then the file `testdisk.log` is created in your current working directory.